# Dynamically populate reactive form field name & field value without hard coding field name in html and component file

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

Hi everyone need small help in populating reactive form dynamically. I m getting data from API not sure how many field name are there, and I need to populate the data in reactive form, data consist of FIELD_NAME & FIELD_VALUE. Right now I m able to achieve this by using form builder

```
myForm = FormGroup
myForm = formbuilder.group({
 FIRST_NAME: new FormControl('', validator.required),
 LAST_NAME: new FormControl('', validator.required),
 FATHER_NAME: new FormControl('', validator.required),
})

and setting value for FIELD_VALUE

myForm.setValue({
FIRST_NAME: arrayList[0].FIELD_VALUE,
LAST_NAME: arrayList[1].FIELD_VALUE,
FATHER_NAME: arrayList[3].FIELD_VALUE
})

and in html 

<mat-form-field>
<mat-label> FIRST_NAME<mat-label>
<input matInput placeholder="FIRST_NAME" formControlName="FIRST_NAME">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
<mat-label> LAST_NAME<mat-label>
<input matInput placeholder="LAST_NAME" formControlName="LAST_NAME">
</mat-form-field>
```

i dont want to hard code the FIELD_NAME in ts file and in html ,

```
formBuilder.group{(
FIRST_NAME: new FormControl('', validator.required),
 LAST_NAME: new FormControl('', validator.required),
 FATHER_NAME: new FormControl('', validator.required),
)}
```

need to populate the form dynamically with FIELD_NAME & FIELD_VALUE.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a fun exercise.

1. In your component, initialize an empty form group.
2. In the `ngOnInit` method, get your API data, iterate over its keys to
   -> Create a new control with the key and its value
   -> Push the key in an array to keep track of your keys

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular";
  form = this.formBuilder.group({}); // Create an empty form group
  apiData = {
    // Get you API data one way or the other
    FIRSTNAME: "John",
    LASTNAME: "Doe",
    FATHERNAME: "John Doe I"
  };
  formFields = []; // Array to keep track of form field keys

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.buildForm(); // Populate your form on component init
  }

  private buildForm() {
    for (const key in this.apiData) {
      // For each key
      this.form.addControl(key, new FormControl(this.apiData[key])); // Add a new control to your form
      this.formFields.push(key); // Push the key in an array
    }
  }
}
```

3. In your template, bind a form element to your form group, iterate over your keys array and use them to set the `label` and the `input`'s `formControlName` (don't forget the `[ ]` to bind to the value)

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <!-- Iterate on your form field keys -->
    <label *ngFor="let field of formFields">
    {{field}} <!-- Use for label -->
    <input [formControlName]="field"> <!-- Bind to your form -->
  </label>
</form>
```

4. Voilà!

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12jmji?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: thanks @Askirkela,  i tried to do the validation part for reactive form
`this.form.addControl(key, new FormControl(this.apiData[key], Validators.required));`
and its not working..even i tried few other ways also....it would be great if you guide me

Comment: the `FormControl` constructor takes an array of `Validators` as its second parameter. Try with `this.form.addControl(key, new FormControl(this.apiData[key], [Validators.required]));` and it should work.

Comment: thanks @Askirkela , i did it other way and its working for me `this.form.addControl(key, this.formBuilder.control(this.apiData[key], Validators.required));` and its works fine. Is this is the correct way or need to make change

Comment: If giving a single validator works, it should be fine. However, since you never know when your requirements will change, I guess it would be cleaner to always use an array of validators (code consistency). I'd say it's up to you/your team